# Downloading from s3 bucket fails while running the s3cmd get from cron job

Tags: linux, amazon-s3

I am running a script to download files from s3 bucket. Running the script in cron. At times, the script fails , but when i run it manually it always works.
Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: What does your script look like? Is there an error message?

Comment: yes , i am checking the exit status for the download command, if it fails it shows the message "file download failes"

Comment: script is like this:
s3cmd get --skip-existing s3://url   /tmp/$DATE/

if [ 0 -ne $? ]; then
   MSG=" file download failed "
   echo $MSG
   exit 1
fi

Comment: I have exported the PATH var as well on top of the script. still its not working.

Comment: You might also want to pipe the output of s3cmd to a file to see the actual error message (eg `s3cmd get ... >>/tmp/s3cmd.out`).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your requirement is to download all new files from Amazon S3, so that you have a local copy of all files (without downloading them repeatedly).

I would recommend using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which has an `aws s3 sync` command. This will synchronize the files from Amazon S3 to your local directory (or the other way). If something goes wrong, it will try to copy the files again on the next sync.

Comment: Hello john ,
Adding to your point my script looks like as below: 
mkdir -p /opt/logs/$DATE
/usr/bin/s3cmd get --skip-existing s3://url/$DATE* /opt/logs/$DATE

if [ 0 -ne $? ]; then
   MSG="Awstat - file download failed. 
   echo $MSG
  fi
If this works fine , then i am performing some operations on the files copied in /opt/logs/$DATE folder. It should process all the files of current date.So , i should be able to get all the files of current date at once. Will sync command do that ? and after its processing i am deleting old files from the /opt/logs/$DATE folder.